# Setting additional colors in theme Material UI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to look for documentation or code example how can I specify addition colors in Material UI theme.

Right now I have following theme configuration

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#B31728"
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#202833"
        }
    },
    ...
```

Now I have a case where I want to use a color for successful operations such as

```
import { green } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

<Fragment>
    {isVerified ? (
        <VerifiedUser style={{ color: green[500] }} />
    ) : (
        <Error color="primary" />
    )}
</Fragment>
```

I want to set the color of **VerifiedUser** Icon in the same way it is set for **Error** Icon. But the theme palette configuration only has primary and secondary intentions. How can I set a color lets say "success" so that I can be able to pass it like

```
<VerifiedUser color="success" />
```

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but as shown in the examples (https://codesandbox.io/s/z24r4218r3) you can add custom stuff outside of `palette`. Handling this as `color` property on you components would require you to implement this yourself and the material-ui components wouldn't know of this custom colors.

Answer (score 3):

For Material-UI, you can only assign `inherit` `primary` `secondary` `default` to color, you can customize `primary` and `secondary` through `createMuiTheme`.

To apply your custom theme into component, use `MuiThemeProvider` :

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  //your component
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Therefore, if you want to generate green theme component, you can create a theme, then use `MuiThemeProvider` to wrap your component.

Code sample(generate green button):

```
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: '#00FF00' }
});

function GreenButton() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="primary">This is green button</Button>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Further reading: [Customize Material-UI with your theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)